# Issue with URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing an issue with my site on cars - Now the problem i am facing with CodeIgniter is that on "new car" section if I select make, the URL is like below.

> http://carandme.com/new-cars/ashok-leyland-cars-in-india?car_type=new&car_type_id=1&maker_id=106&maker_identifier=ashok_leyland&model_id=&model_identifier=

but I want a URL like this.

> http://carandme.com/new-cars/ashok-leyland-cars-in-india

Similarly I am also facing issue in refine search on same page i.e if I select two car, the URL doesn't changes but the parameters do. Is there any way for this to be without parameter.

Comment: you can use uri segment, see here -  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: I would rather advise you for not changing the URL. the url right now is more user friendly and SEO friendly.

Comment: Please don't add your contact details to posts here. We're a Q&A site - we want questions to be well-formatted, well-written examples of problems useful to a wide audience. Stack Overflow is not a forum `:)`.

Comment: Is the first URL (with the query string) the result of a search form?

Answer (score 0):

$input1 = $this->input->post('user_search1');
$input2 = $this->input->post('user_search2');

$user_input = array($input1, $input2); //making array of user search Inputs
$search_field_name = array("search_col_name1", "search_col_name2"); //original column name of table fro searching

//combining to send it as uri latter
$searchparams_uri = array_combine($search_field_name, $user_input);

//removing the keys and values from the array if Values is null or not set
$searchparams_uri = array_filter($searchparams_uri);

// Convert to associative array $this->terms_uri to segments to append to base_url
$keys = $this->uri->assoc_to_uri($this->terms);

$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/controller/method_name/'.'/'.$keys.'/';

You will get URL like this:
index.php/controller/method_name/search_col_name1/input1/search_col_name1/input1

Break and Make according to your need. Question are welcome.